# Dynamic variable in C#?

Tags: c#, dynamic-variables

Is it possible to use a dynamic variable (not sure about naming) in C#?

In PHP, I can do

```
$var_1 = "2";
$var_2 = "this is variable 2";

$test = ${"var_".$var_1};

echo $test;

output: this is variable 2;
```

Can we do this in C#?

Comment: let's not compare a scripting language with a programming language. You can do the same in plain old ASP as it is also a scripting language, but C# is a programming language that uses OOP. Just to add, you have Dynamic Variables in .NET 4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C#, you use [dictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) to associate values with strings.

Comment: not exactly what I wanted, but dictionary would be just fine as well! thank you!

Answer (score 9):

No, basically. The compiler doesn't guarantee that method variables will exist (in their form as written), or with names...

If they were fields (instance or static), then you could use reflection to get the values; but not method variables. For what you want, perhaps use a dictionary as a substitute?

```
var vars = new Dictionary<string,object>();
vars["var_1"] = "2";
vars["var_2"] = "this is variable 2";

Console.WriteLine(vars["var_" + vars["var_1"]]);
```

Comment: I don't understand this part of the second sentence "method variables will exist (in their form as written) or with names...". I understand the rest of your answer, I just don't understand the meaning of that sentence. Could you clarify what that means?

Comment: He means that the variable names are not guaranteed to be saved until runtime, so even if you could do something like that, "$var_2" wouldn't exist after compiling.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works with local variables (and most likely it doesn't since they're stored as indexes), but you could access class properties through reflection.

Answer (score 1):

If your `var` is a class field, then you can use the static [`GetField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53seyfee.aspx) method from class `Type` to obtain field information, such as its current value.

Answer (score 1):

You are not looking for simple arrays?

```
string[] myArray = new string[2];

myArray[0] = "2";
myArray[1] = "this is variable 2"
```

Otherwhise dictionary is the way to go.