# define arrays with dynamic names

Tags: c#

I try to define double arrays but their names are in a string array. Is it possible to do something like that :

```
string[] arrayNames = new string[] {"a", "b", "c"};

double[] arrayNames[0] ; // problem is here.I try to give names dynamically
```

ps: Of course this code doesn't work ;) 
Thanks...

Comment: Is there a reason you need specific names instead of just creating a two-dimensional array and iterating over that instead?

Comment: You don't name arrays in .NET. What are you trying to do? A dictionary could be appropriate.

Comment: Why? Once compiled no will be abled to see your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use a Dictionary?

```
Dictionary<string, double[]> doubleArrays = new Dictionary<string, double[]>();

doubleArrays.Add("a", new double[] { 1.0, 1.2 });
// etc.
double[] someArray = doubleArrays["a"];
```

Comment: Best answer. Moreover due to the incomprehensibly phrased question.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the `IDictionary<string, IEnumerable>`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have "dynamic variable names" in C# - see for example [Dynamic variable in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282888/dynamic-variable-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need the array of dynamic objects?

```
var array = new[] {new {Foo=1}, new {Foo=2}};
```