# opposite of nameof (string of variable name to variable) C#

Tags: c#

Say I have a List called this_list. If I make a string that says "this_list", how can I turn that string into the actual variable? It should do the opposite of what nameof would do.

```
List<string> this_list = new List<string> { "wow","amazing" };
string str = "this_list";
// str to this_list somehow
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I can't see how it's useful and I see no way of accomplishing it.

Comment: Have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723960/convert-string-to-variable-name
and here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831273/converting-string-to-variable-name

Comment: @Palle Due I have a load of string lists and I need to get only a certain one based off a string.

Comment: Then why not use a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`?

Answer (score 0):

If `this_list` is a local variable (like in your example), you can't. Local variable names are lost during compilation.

If `this_list` is a field or property, you can use [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection).