# Read attributes of an object without using . operator in c#

Tags: c#, class, attributes

I want to display attribute of an object based on the input string . If input is "x" and Object is "obj", i want to display something like "obj.x" without using if,switch or other conditional operators. Can someone help me?

```
public void My_Method(String input)
{
MyClass  tempVariable=getMyClass();

display something like ---->  tempVariable.input
}

public getMyClass()
{
MyClass value = MyClass();
value.x=10;
value.y=20;
.........
return value;

}


public class MyClass
{
public int x {get;set;}
public int y {get ;set;}
......
}
```

The purpose of this is as follows
Im receiving a dynamic ExpanObject type from a API. There will a lot of name value pairs and one name value pair contains value as comma separated list of some variable names. I have to get the value of these variables

Comment: What is actually the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: So you mean that the `String` input parameter to your method could be either x, y or z (as strings) based on which you need to access those instance variables of MyClass ?

Comment: If so, I don't think so what you are thinking about doing is feasible in `C#`. At the most, you can use `dictionaries`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282888/dynamic-variable-in-c and key in those instance variables.

Comment: Im receiving a dynamic ExpanObject type from a API. There will a lot of name value pairs and one name value pair contains value as comma separated list of some variable names. I have to get the value of these variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use reflection

```
var fVal = obj.GetType().GetField("x").GetValue(obj);
```

or

```
var pVal = obj.GetType().GetProperty("x").GetValue(obj,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Reflection (less perf ) or Expression Trees ([link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/09/14/generating-dynamic-methods-with-expression-trees-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

I preefer expreesion tree:

```
 public static class PropertyHelper
    {
        public static string GetName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> e)
        {
            var member = (MemberExpression)e.Body;
            return member.Member.Name;
        }

        public static Type GetPropertyType<T>(Expression<Func<T>> e)
        {
            var member = (MemberExpression)e.Body;
            return member.Type;
        }
    }
```

And to get names  is easy:

```
MyClass tempVariable = getMyClass();
  string varName = PropertyHelper.GetName(() => tempVariable);
 string propName = PropertyHelper.GetName(() => tempVariable.x);
```