# variable variable name C#

Tags: c#, php, variables

I am new in C#, I use to program PHP.

I want to do same thing that is done in PHP code below for C#.

```
  <?php
     for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
    {
     $tempVar="$newVar".$i;

     echo $$tempVar; //to print the content of $newVar0 to $newvar9       
    }
  ?>
```

Is the same option, of changing variable name dynamically, available in C#. Please Guide. Thank you

Comment: see if System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print is what you're looking for

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic variable in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282888/dynamic-variable-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

PHP and C# both have very different syntax. You must start learning by yourself from online tutorials.
Your answer is

```
var newVar ="This is test";
var var1= newVar;
Console.WriteLine(var1);
```

Tutorial Sources (learn step by step)

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/

http://techfunda.com/Howto/c

Comment: Hi, Thank you for reply. I have changed the example PHP code, I hope this can explain clearly my question.

Comment: This is very old, but it does not answer the question.
The question pertains to PHP's Variable variables, where you can access a variable via a variable string, for instance. It is not simply asking the syntax in c# to access another variable.
See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php (particularly Example #1 Variable property example)

In the user's code you see `"$newVar".$i` which is being used to access a variable `$newVar0` - your answer does not explain how to create or access variables dynamically - only how to create and access them statically.